# SOAP / MTOM and type hexBinary

Tags: spring, jaxb, mtom

We are creating the server side for a SOAP based service that uses MTOM/XOP to receive binary files (zip).

The xsd for the service has the following element definition for the binary file:

<xs:element name="thebinaryfile" type="xs:hexBinary" xmime:contentType="application/octet-stream"/>

We have been using the same approach as demo'ed here (but without all the repository classes etc):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples/tree/main/mtom/server

The issue is that when the type "hexBinary" is used, the get'er on the generated request object always returns null. If we change the type to "base64Binary", we get the proper value populated in the byte array.

We send identical requests from SoapUI and see that they reaches the server as expected. But something happens on the receiving side when the libraries are trying to populate the request objects when usng "hexBinary".

Any ideas? Is there no support for hexBinary in MTOM/XOP?